# Save file in google cloud storage from android application?

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage

How to save file with expiration time(i.e file will be automatically deleted from storage) in google cloud storage from android application & get public url of file stored in bucket.

I have created bucket & set public access to it but unable to find any way of storing file in google cloud storage without any authentication.

Read google cloud documentation but there is documentation specific to android.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a TTL for a specific object, but you can configure a global TTL on the bucket via [lifecycle config](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle).

As for authenticating uploads from the Android application, the best way is to use [signed urls](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls).